# DDD Domain Specific/General Infrastructure

Tags: architecture, dependency-injection, domain-driven-design

Regarding domain infrastructure is it OK to think of them as:

- General: How to send an email / Read configuration file, etc..
- Specific: How to send an activation code to a new user (domain entity)

Where if i think of dependencies:

- *Domain* < References > *General Infrastructure* (for Logging, General Exceptions, etc..)
- *Specific Infrastructure* < References > *General Infrastructure & Domain* (to get infrastructure related operation interfaces like **IActivationCodeSender** and be able to implement an **EmailActivationCodeSender** & an **SmsActivationCodeSender**)

My application layer in that case will be responsible to pass (DI resolved) the desired activation method to my domain entity, let us say:

```
User.Register(IActivationCodeSender activationCodeSender)
{
   // Register user and generate activation code 1234
   ...
   activationCodeSender.Send(this, "1234");
}
```

Is this bad? should i instead work on my (General) Infrastructure to make sure it supports sending sms / email in a unified manner *(I'm afraid such cases might introduce complexity to my General Infrastructure)* and remove this Specific Infrastructure in the sense that such layer would mix the business logic with Infrastructure related operations? so instead i would use the following:

Two (General) implementations for the **INotificationSender**; an **EmailNotificationSender** and an **SmsNotificationSender**

```
User.Register(INotificationSender activationCodeSender)
{
   // Register user and generate activation code 1234
   ...
  // this.NotificationAddressInfo includes email address and mobile phone #

   activationCodeSender.Send(new Notification(this.NotificationAddressInfo, "Your activation code is 1234"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you consider using the [Dependency inversion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) that has these basic principles (from Wikipedia):

> 1. *High-level modules should not depend on low-level modules. Both
>      should depend on abstractions.*
> 2. *Abstractions should not depend
>      upon details. Details should depend upon abstractions.*

So I would put all the interfaces like `IActivationSender` in your domain, and then implement this interface in a separate infrastructure project. As you mention, use DI to inject the desired implementation in your application service (or in a domain service).

This way you can avoid using the [Douple dispatch pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) where you pass the implementation of the interface directly to a `domain entity`:

> User.Register(INotificationSender activationCodeSender)

And instead have something like:

`UserService.Register(user);`

Where UserService could be a domain service with the correct INotificationSender injected.

A completely other way of solving the issue could be to use Domain events (see [Udi Dahans article](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/14/domain-events-salvation/)). Following this pattern, your User entity would raise a "UserCreated" event that the INotificationSender would in turn subscribe to. This way you decouple the concern of sending notification messages from the User entity.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a subscription once user registered. And put your code generation, notification logic in the subscription aggregator. It will control what need to be sent and what is the sequence. what to do if fail, etc. And your notification can be very part of Infrastructure since it can know nothing about your domain. Just get email and send out.

Answer (score 0):

There is no domain infrastructure.
Your customer does not care about how you are going to send e-mails.

Comment: So you think Infrastructure projects should not reference domain projects but rather work independently of any domain (no domain infrastructure)?

Comment: Arnis is correct about there being no domain infrastructure. Any infrastructure interface should be moved to the Application level and upwards, where you could have an Application Service or a DomainEventHandler which in turn could demand an INotificationSender via its constructor. The domain should be 100% infrastructure ignorant, even about infrastructure interfaces.